# Hive error when creating an external table (state=08S01,code=1)

Tags: hadoop, hive, thrift

I'm trying to create an external table in Hive, but keep getting the following error:

```
create external table foobar (a STRING, b STRING) row format delimited fields terminated by "\t" stored as textfile location "/tmp/hive_test_1375711405.45852.txt";
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask (state=08S01,code=1)
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask (state=08S01,code=1)
Aborting command set because "force" is false and command failed: "create external table foobar (a STRING, b STRING) row format delimited fields terminated by "\t" stored as textfile location "/tmp/hive_test_1375711405.45852.txt";"
```

The contents of `/tmp/hive_test_1375711405.45852.txt` are:

```
abc\tdef
```

I'm connecting via the `beeline` command line interface, which uses Thrift `HiveServer2`.

System:

- Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.0
- Hive 0.10.0-cdh4.3.0
- Beeline 0.10.0-cdh4.3.0
- Client OS - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

Comment: i executed the command successfuly in my system

Comment: have you had a prev hive installation which you uninstalled?

Comment: Thanks for trying this out on your system, sonic. I should have mentioned that we previously had CDH 4.1 installed and recently upgraded to CDH 4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I was pointing the external table at a file in HDFS instead of a directory. The cryptic Hive error message really threw me off.

The solution is to create a directory and put the data file in there. To fix this for the above example, you'd create a directory under `/tmp/foobar` and place `hive_test_1375711405.45852.txt` in it. Then create the table like so:

```
create external table foobar (a STRING, b STRING) row format delimited fields terminated by "\t" stored as textfile location "/tmp/foobar";
```

Answer (score -1):

We faced similar problem in our company (Sentry, hive, and kerberos combination). We solved it by removing all privileges from non fully defined `hdfs_url`. For example, we changed `GRANT ALL ON URI '/user/test' TO ROLE test;` to `GRANT ALL ON URI 'hdfs-ha-name:///user/test' TO ROLE test;`.

You can find the privileges for a specific URI in the Hive database (mysql in our case).